# Which parts of a URL must be encoded?

Tags: http, url, encoding, uri, urlencode

Using `POST` is easy and automatic: just use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` or whatever.

#### Instead, what parts should be encoded in a `GET` request?

The whole *query* string? Just the *parameter values* but not the *names*? And the *fragment*?

Maybe also the *path*? But I'm pretty sure that I shouldn't encode the *host* or the *scheme* (there are encoding and specs for international domains, like in Japanese etc.).

Hence the question is more about the URI

---

I was surprised to not find a clear specific answer on SO, and on the internet too.

Comment: "The Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) is the premier Internet standards body". They publish RFCs, so [Search RFC URI](https://www.google.com/search?q=rfc+uri).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to encode the parts of the url (excluding the domain name) that may contain **symbols** and **non ASCII characters** excluding the slashes “/“ and the operands used by query strings (?, = and &).

**Note**: if you encode all the second part of the url together including the slashes and the operands used by the query strings, this part will be considered all as a single value and the url may not work properly.

Comment: So the list is: parameter-names (excluding *"&"*), parameter-values (excluding *"="*), path-parts (excluding *"/"*) and fragment (excluding *"#"*); right? So theoretically functions/classes like *encodeURI (JS) / rawurlencode (PHP) / URLEncoder (Java) / urllib.urlencode (Python) / etc* should all take care of encoding everything at once, when passing them the URI, I suppose?

Comment: Yes that’s the complete list, and yes most of these functions should take care of encoding everything at once and works perfectly except if you are using one of the excluded symbols as a value (for example if you’re passing a slash in the query string value, in this case these functions will consider the slash as a route separator but in reality it’s a query string value). It’s a very rare case but technically possible.